# Modify strings within a vector? (Without using loops)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iterator

I'm trying to take a vector of strings and remove every character that's not a letter (number, symbols, etc.) I'm also not trying to use loops.

So here's an example of a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> a = {"he2llo*", "3worl$d"};
```

And I want the string returned to look like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> a = {"hello", "world"};
```

Right now I'm trying to use the transfrom and erase algorithms, but I can't get the syntax right.

This is obviously incomplete, but it's the basic setup of what I have so far:

```
int trim(std::vector<std::string> a){
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.erase())
```

Comment: You need to specify the output range of `transform`. Also, you can write a lambda that removes the non-letters from the strings.

Comment: You *do* realise that everything using `begin()` and `end()` is almost certainly going to be looping under the covers, yes? Other than *slightly* shorter source code, I'm not sure what you'll gain by avoiding explicit loops.

Comment: @paxdiablo One could argue that it conveys intent more clearly.

Comment: Can also use recursion I guess..

Comment: I'm not allowed to use loops for this. I guess writing the lambda is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: if someone could write it out I would appreciate it.

Comment: Won't you accept an answer? if you need more clarification, plz, let us know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)  on the vector and then use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) on the strings, as follows

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> a = {"he2llo*", "3worl$d"};
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),[](auto & str){
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [] (auto & character){return !isalpha(character);}), str.end());
    });

    for(auto const & el : a)
        std::cout << el << " ";

}
The output:
hello world
```

Comment: Probably no reason to pass `character` as a reference since you're not changing it. And, if I was a smart-a** educator, I'd take marks of for doing the output loop with `for` instead of another `for_each` :-) But this is a bit simpler than transform, so kudos for that.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string remove_bad_characters(std::string input, std::string result)
{
    if (input.size() == 0)
    {
        return result;
    }

    if (!isalpha(input[0]))
    {
        return remove_bad_characters(input.substr(1), result);
    }

    result += input[0];
    return remove_bad_characters(input.substr(1), result);
}

std::vector<std::string> edit_bad_strings(std::vector<std::string> input, std::size_t index)
{
    if (index == input.size())
    {
        return input;
    }

    input[index] = remove_bad_characters(input[index], "");
    return edit_bad_strings(input, index + 1);
}


int main() {

    std::cout<<remove_bad_characters("h!ello!", "")<<"\n";
    std::vector<std::string> good = edit_bad_strings(std::vector<std::string>{"h!ell@o", "wo0rl-d"}, 0);

    for (std::string str : good)
    {
        std::cout<<str<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::for_each` instead of loop to traverse each element.
Then you can apply `std::transform` on each element of vector.

**You can refer -**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

Comment: Why don't you show an actual snippet of code that solves the problem as well?

Comment: "You can use std::for_each instead of loop" - `std::for_each` *is* a loop internally.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it with the `algorithm` header and lambda functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strArr = {"he2llo*", "3worl$d"};
    std::transform(strArr.begin(), strArr.end(), strArr.begin(), [](std::string &str) -> std::string {
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char chr) -> bool {
            return ! isalpha(chr);
        }), str.end());
        return str;
    });

    std::for_each(strArr.begin(), strArr.end(), [](const auto &str) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    });

    return 0;
}
```

The outer lambda processes each string to erase specific characters by using `remove_if`, while the inner lambda just controls *which* characters are removed. Whether that's more readable than a loop-based solution is open to debate :-)

Comment: Moving the lambda out of the transform, and naming it, might help readability. Still subjective of course, but just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++20 std::erase_if

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> a = {"he2llo*", "3worl$d"};
  std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), 
    [](auto& str) { 
      std::erase_if(str, [](const auto& chr){return !isalpha(chr);}); 
      return std::move(str);
      });
  for (const auto& str: a){
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in different ways with STL `<algorithm>`s, i implemented a functor to process each word :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

class Processing{

public:

    std::string operator()(std::string& value){

        for_each(value.begin(), value.end(), [&](char v) mutable throw() ->
                 void {
                    auto fetch = std::find_if( value.begin(), value.end(), [&](char v)mutable throw()->
                                              bool{
                                                  return(!isalpha(v));
                                                  });
                    if(*fetch){
                        value.erase( fetch );
                    }
                 });
        return value;
    }

};

int main()
{

  std::vector<std::string> values = {"44h%ello333","%w%or333ld21"};

  std::for_each(values.begin(),values.end(), Processing());

  std::for_each(values.begin(),values.end(), [](std::string& value)->
                void {
                    std::cout<<value<<" ";
                    });

    return 0;
}
```